# $F_p,L_p$ both prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

It is well known that if the $n$ th Fibonacci number is a prime then it follows $n$ must also be a prime.

So we wonder if $F_p $ is prime or not. 
It is believed there are infinitely many Fibonacci primes.
It is also believed there are infinitely many prime Lucas numbers ( or Lucas primes ).

So I wonder , are there many primes $p$ such that both $F_p $ and $L_p$ are prime ?

I have not checked mod 100.

Since fibonacci and Lucas numbers are related I wondered about that.

I know $ L_q = 1 \mod q $ for every odd prime $q$.
Not sure if that is related.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A080327  might be of interest.

Comment: Note that the statement $F_n\ prime\implies n\ prime$ is not true ($n=4$ is a counterexample)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the numbers are related : $$L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$$ The list of known prime numbers of both kinds reveals that we have a prime pair $(F_n,L_n)$ for the positive integers $$4\ 5\ 7\ 11\ 13\ 17\ 47$$ as well as the surprising pair for $n=148\ 091$ for which however $F_n$ is "only" a probable prime.

For both kinds of numbers, we can expect infinite many primes because of the relative slow growth rate (only exponential), but I would not expect another pair. I am already very surprised of the huge pair above (more than $30\ 000$ digits each !)

Comment: we are in effect looking for $n$ such that $F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$ and  $F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}$ are prime making $F_{n+1}^2-F_{n-1}^2$ a semiprime.

Comment: In fact, I did not notice this.

Comment: Is $F_{n+1}^2$ + $F_{n-1}^2$ infinitely often a semiprime ? You made me wonder about that. Maybe semiprime heuristics give a better estimate for the number of solutions ? Mainly @Roddy

Comment: yeah but you can also straight up calculate it with $[ \phi^{2n+2}-\phi^{2n-2} ]$ forced to be a 3-almost prime(the brackets indicate rounding) as if you divide this by 5 you get the difference of squares.  See sieve of sundaram you can build an almost prime sieve by restricted iteration.